# Each element in a set can occur at most once in any order with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm getting input from a file which looks like:

```
Key0=Value0;Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2
```

Assuming that there are 3 keys, I need to verify that each key occurs at most once, except Key0 which occurs exactly once and will be at the beginning, but they may not be ordered. Currently I am using a regex that looks like:

```
"^Key0=[\\w](;Key1=[\\w])?(;Key2=[\\w])?(;Key2=[\\w])?;?"
```

In reality there are a lot more than 3 keys, so something overly verbose may not be feasible. The idea is that this should match the first string presented above, but also the following strings:

```
Key0=Value0;Key1=Value1
Key0=Value0;Key2=Value2
Key0=Value0;Key2=Value2;Key1=Value1
```

and not any of these strings:

```
Key0=Value0;Key1=Value1;Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2
Key0=Value0;Key1=Value1;Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2;Key2=Value2
Key0=Value0;Key2=Value2;Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2
```

etc.

I'm not sure if back referencing groups or the `(?>...)` syntax might be useful. Any ideas are appreciated. (Also I'm using the Java regex engine).

Comment: I assuming the `?>` in that last paragraph is referring to atomic groups. When talking about the special group constructs, I find it's best to include the parentheses.  I always have to stop and puzzle out the meaning of `?>`, `?:`, etc. when I encounter them outside that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex seems to meet your needs:

```
"^Key0=\\w+(?:;(?:(?!\\1)Key1()|(?!\\2)Key2()|(?!\\3)Key3())=\\w+)*$"
```

...or the readable version:

```
(?x)
^Key0=\w+
(?:;
  (?:
    (?!\1)Key1() |
    (?!\2)Key2() |
    (?!\3)Key3()
  )=\w+
)*$
```

As each key name is matched, the empty group following it matches as well.  Though it doesn't consume any characters, it's still said to have participated in the match.  From then on, backreferences to that group will succeed (again consuming nothing).  And so the negative lookahead *preceding* each name prevents that name from being matched more than once.

But don't use this unless you absolutely have to (i.e. if the regex is the only part of the problem you have any control over).  Almost any other approach is preferable to having to feed and care for this beast. :D

Answer (score 1):

Add this negative look-ahead to the start of your regex:

```
^(?!.*Key\d+=(.*?);.*Key\d+=\1(;|$))
```

This uses a back reference to assert no duplicate values.

I would also simplify the main regex to:

```
^(Key\d+=[^;]+(;|$))+
```

Putting it all together, with correct escaping for java:

```
^(?!.*Key\\d+=(.*?);.*Key\\d+=\1(;|$))(Key\\d+=[^;]+(;|$))+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't recommend using regex for the entire list.

Instead, you could split on `;` like so:

```
String string = "Key0=Value0;Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2";
String[] keys = string.split(";");
```

Then loop through the resulting collection, like so: (apologies, I'm not a java programmer and can't provide the exact syntax):

```
for (String pair : keys)
{
    String[] key = pair.split("=");
    ## replace 'pair' with key[0] ##
}

for (String key : keys)
{
    ## check for duplicate key in keys ##
}
```